# Woocommerce products link appears in Footer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Underscores template and I want to integrate woocommerce.
I added to functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', '_s_wrapper_start', 10 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', '_s_wrapper_end', 10 );

function _s_wrapper_start() {
    echo '<div id="primary" class="content-area">';
}

function _s_wrapper_end() {
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Everything is OK on the Homepage, but when I open a product page, almost all my content is linked to a product even if the source code is clean. 
For example, the map in footer and all the h3/h4 are linked to a product.
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sfLi.png)  [Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quKJs.jpg)

I don't recall modifying woocommerce.

I've been looking for an answer to ths problem all day long and I don't know what else to do! Any Ideas?
I can't provide you with a link as the website is on my localhost, but if needed i'll put it online.
I don't know which file you need to find the problem, I can provide you with any information you would need.

Thanks!
Nicolas

Comment: From the code you have provided it looks like you are adding 2 closing `div` tags but only opening one div, this will likely create an issue in your HTML with other `div` closing early.

Comment: Indeed, there are two closing div, thanks for your answer.
However, the same problem is still there even when i delete one closing div.

Is there any way I can provide you with more information you would need?

Comment: @NicolasPipo Can you please provide page link ?

Comment: Thanks Prafulla Kumar Sahu, but the website is local hosted right now.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem!
If anyone meet this problem one day, don't forget:
     `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );` at the end of *content-product.php* !
    I deleted it, and that's why I had this problem!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent! Been struggling with this for a while now. Thanks for the heads up